# How dynamically give link to the image?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to the PHP Programming. I retrieve image dynamically from the folder and fetch into the webpage.Now, I want to know how will I give link to the image to redirect to the other page? The most important thing is, I retrieve image dynamically not statically.

This is the code I use to retrieve the image:

```php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM product1");
$file_path = 'image/';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) {
  $src=$file_path.$row['image'];
  echo "<img align='left' src=".$src." height='430' width='466' > ";
}
```

Comment: add code how you retrieving the image dynamically ?

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM product1");
$file_path = 'image/';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data ))
{
$src=$file_path.$row['image'];

echo "<img align='left'  src=".$src." height='430' width='466'   > ";

}

Comment: What other page?  If you just want to output a link in PHP, then just add it to the HTML markup and use a server-side variable for the dynamic parts.  The fact that it's a link doesn't make it different from any other markup.

Comment: Thanks for your response david.I want a link for the image.I don't know how to give link when i retrieve image dynamically.That's why i am asking.Thank You

Comment: and where is the 'dinamically link'? I don't see it in your code

Comment: dynamically means,i retrieve image using URL file path.I retrieve all image dynamically by using this method.how i retrieve image statically from the image folder.

Answer (score 0):

write the code like below

```
<a href="redirect_page.php"><img src="your_folder_name/<?php echo $image_name;?>" /></a>
```

think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your `img` tag within an anchor tag.

```
"<a href='".$link."'><img align='left' src='".$src."' height='430' width='466' > </a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response @nauphal:I want the link for individual image.not for all image.(Your coding is like giving link to all images).In image folder i am having 6image means each image i have to set link.Thank you.

Comment: @madhan: You can generate the link with in your `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM product1"); 
$file_path = 'image/';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) {
    $src=$file_path.$row['image']; 
    $link = 'YOUR_REDIRECT_LINK';
    echo "<a href='".$link"'><img align='left' src=".$src." height='430' width='466' ></a>";
 }
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add an explanation to your code, given the simplicity of the question, the OP might not be used to what's happening in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM product1");
$file_path = 'image/';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) {
   $src=$file_path.$row['image'];
   echo "<a href='redirect.php'><img align='left' src='".$src."' height='430' width='466' ></a>";
}
```

Above is the same code you supplied, with the following changes:
1 - I've wrapped the image in an anchor tag, to an example redirect page (redirect.php)
2 - I've added single quotes around the src attribute's value, on the img element

Comment: @gamma.It is not working gamma.It will not go to the redirect page.

Comment: @gamma, welcome to SO. It's usually recommended that you offer some explanatory text around a code snippet in a response to explain why this will answer the question (what did you change and why).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image that you're echoing in an  tag.

Then, using the php variable $src, build a dynamic link for each image:

If you want it to open in a new window, use the target="_blank" attribute in the link.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM product1");
$file_path = 'image/';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) {

  $src=$file_path.$row['image'];

  echo "<a href="{$src}" target="_blank"><img align='left' src=".$src." height='430' width='466' ></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can give use this code-
{{ HTML::image($your _table_name->image, $your _table_name->title) }}

and all the images from the database will come.